# Creating table efficiently in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm implementing the cky algorithm and I tried it once with list of lists in python and once with numpy.zeros and the list of lists is faster every time. I would think numpy would be faster, but I am new to using it and it is likely that I am not writing it in the most efficient way possible. It is also possible that I am just using a small dataset and list of lists are just faster on smaller datasets.

The only bit that is different is the instantialization of the tables:

straight python:

```
  table = [[[] for i in range(length)] for j in range(length)]
```

and numpy:

```
 table = np.zeros((n_dimension, n_dimension), dtype=object)
  for i in range(n_dimension):
      for j in range(n_dimension):
          table[i][j] = []
```

I think that numpy is acting slower because I am not optimizing how I form my table, while the pythonic way is as efficient as that can be written. How can I make a similar, optimized implementation in numpy so that I can accurately assess the time differences between the two? Or are list of lists just faster in this case? At what point does numpy become more efficient than list of lists?

Comment: `numpy`arrays are faster when doing whole-array operations on numeric dtype arrays.  Then it uses compiled methods.  With object dtype, arrays use the same object referencing as lists.  Iteration on such an array is bit slower than on a list (but the same sort of iteration on a numeric dtype is even slower).

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. So if I'm storing objects in an array it makes more sense to just use the regular pythonic lists. Is there no way to set an np array with empty arrays for i j when initializing it?

Comment: It's not just the setting up of that array that will be slower.  Nearly every operation will be slower - except for things like `reshape` were `dtype` doesn't matter.

Comment: If this is about storing text, maybe indeed numpy is slower. Is it a problem that it is slower?